# How can I have different caption delimiters for captions and contcaptions?

Tags: captions, memoir

I'm using the memoir class and have a figure that is continued on the next page. The markup is roughly this:

```
\captiondelim{: }

\begin{figure}
  % ...
  \caption{Foo bar}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
  % ...
  \contcaption{(Continued)}
\end{figure}
```

This results in two figures with the captions

> Figure 1: Foo bar

and

> Figure 1: (Continued)

Is there any chance to change the caption delimiter (automatically) for "contcaption"s, such that the result would be (the colon must still be there for normal captions though):

> Figure 1 (Continued)

I tried to understand what the `\concaption` command actually does, but it didn't look like there was a simple solution...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that in a `figure` environment you just have a `\contcaption`, never accompanied by a `\caption` command, which seems a reasonable assumption, you can do it with

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\captiondelim{: }
\preto{\contcaption}{\captiondelim{ }} % change \captiondelim

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]
  % ...
  \caption{Foo bar}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htp]
  % ...
  \contcaption{(Continued)}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htp]
  % ...
  \caption{Oh}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: ahh, that was a good one, hadn't though of that.

Answer (score 4):

Not really no. I think the easiest thing is to use

```
\newcommand\mycontcaption[1]{
  \begingroup
  \captiondelim{~}
  \contcaption{#1}
  \endgroup
}
```

and then use

```
\mycontcaption{(Continued)}
```

Comment: That's perfect! I didn't know about "begingroup" and "endgroup"...

Answer (score 2):

An automatic solution can be obtained with the `caption` package: it has a `\ContinuedFloat` switch that defines the figure environment in which it is used, as of type `continuedfloat` for which we can define a specific formatting:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{continued}{ #1~(continued)}
\captionsetup[ContinuedFloat]{format=continued}

\begin{document}

  \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[scale = 0.4]{Piero_di_Cosimo_1}
    \caption{Piero di Cosimo}
    \end{figure}

  \begin{figure}\ContinuedFloat
        \centering
        \includegraphics[scale = 0.3]{Piero_di_Cosimo_2}
    \caption{}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]